# Handle variable that could be None

Tags: python, django

Although this is django related, it's really just a general, programming efficiency question.

I have a template that, depending on the scenario, will get and return either one or two forms.  If it returns one form, the variable that holds the second form will be None.

I need to check if the forms are valid.  Similar to [an example I read online](http://disturbyte.posterous.com/using-one-form-to-edit-two-models), I'm checking .is_valid() on both forms in the same if statement.  But this unsurprisingly throws an error (NoneType object has no attribute is_valid) if the second form is None.

**What is the best way to check that both forms are valid without incurring an error if the second form is None?**

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = form_dict[modelname][1](request.POST) 
    try:
        form_two = form_dict[modelname][2](request.POST)
    except:
        form_two = None

    if form.is_valid() and form_two.is_valid():
        # Do some stuff and save the data from the form(s)      
    else:
        try:
            form = form_dict[modelname][1]()
            form_two = form_dict[modelname][2]()
        except:
            form_two = None
```

Comment: Can't you check with an IF statement if form_two is None and If it isn't, validate it?

Comment: Is this an efficient solution?  It seems like I would have to write that if statement and then encase the if statement for the first form's validation in a sub-if statement.

Comment: What do you mean by efficient? It is certainly computationally efficient (checking if an object is None is one of the fastest things you can do). And you don't need to encase it in a sub-if- see @BrendanLong's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the general case of checking if something is `None`.. just check it?

```
if x is not None and x.is_valid():
   ...
```

In Python, `or` and `and` both [short circuit](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not), meaning that in the expression `x and y`, `y` is not evaluated if `x` is `false` (since the expression is false no matter what `y` is).

Comment: I should have clarified.  I need both forms if form_two is not None.  So the first bit of code doesn't work for this example.  In terms of just checking the variable, I need both forms checked for validity if they exist.  It seems like your second bit of code will only check the first form?

Comment: @Ed. - The second bit is general purpose. Just extend it to as many variables as you need. The simple version is "check if it's `None`, then check if it's valid", and do that for each variable you need to check.

Comment: @BrendanLong is exactly right. Do this as `if form_two is not None and form.is_valid() and form_two.is_valid():`

Comment: gotcha.  didn't understand about the short circuiting the first time I read through.  I changed the statement to the following: if form_two is not None and form.is_valid() and form_two.is_valid() or form_two is None and form.is_valid():.  This lets me capture all instances of proper validation and I later simply skip saving form_two if it is None.