# How to sum items in updatecursor with None data types

Tags: python, arcpy

Working in python with ESRI's arcpy, I'm trying to sum values across multiple fields with an arcpy updateCursor . I'm trying to convert the None items to an 0. However, I can't figure out a way to convert the None items.  I'm open to anything.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class, score_fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        [0 if x==None else x+4 for x in row]
        print row
        row[len(score_fields)-1] = sum(row[i] for i in range(len(score_fields)))
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Returns:

```
[-4, -4, None, None, -4, None, -4, -4]
```

with error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at this [handle NoneTypes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316697/handle-variable-that-could-be-none)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update `row` by assigning the result of the list comprehension to `row`:

```
for row in cursor:
    row = [0 if x is None else x+4 for x in row]
```

Also, note that since there is only one `None` object, better to test with `is` than use `==`; more Pythonic, more performant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement to filter the `None` values in your list:

```
sum(row[i] for i in range(len(score_fields)) if row[i] is not None)
```

Comment: This worked too, thanks.  Moses' answer fit better into my other, not listed, code.